# Rails server problems? App won't load in web browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, powder

I'm trying to run my rails project but the webpage is stuck at loading when I'm trying to access the myproject.dev. Powder starts without any problems and Guard doesn't pick up any
errors.

Rails server works but generates this error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 17 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2:/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global', execute `gem env` for more information
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
```

I recently switched from rbenv to rvm, but I had the same issue before that.
  Tried googling but can't really find an solutions.

Update:

Tried reinstalling railities as well as rails but it didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

there is problem with `railties` gem 
try to `gem uninstall railties` it then `gem install railties` again... then only this will work
OR
do `gem install rails`

Comment: Done, and it didn't  help.

Comment: this is one way of solving problem. If u used another post it here

Comment: I did as you suggested and it didn't fix my problem.

Comment: It's the same as before. Nothing in guard and the web page just keeps loading. It also says Resolving Host in the bottom left corner, but it did before too.

Comment: rails server works? 
run `bundle show railties` and post output here.

Comment: Yes, rails server works. `bundle show railties` -> `/Users/myuser/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87576/discussion-between-garry-and-bork).